# Web scraping with Laravel and Selenium

Tags: php, laravel, selenium, web-scraping

I am currently using Python in web scraping. I used Selenium and Beautifulsoup libraries in order to scrape. I recently know the Selenium works for php/Laravel.

My question is, could I scrape the web using Laravel + Selenium web driver? If yes can you provide me some links or repositories in order for me to study it? I was forced to use php/Laravel in my scraping work because they said that php is easy to deploy/execute in server for real time scraping.

Comment: Python is probably easy to deploy too. It seems a bad idea to rewrite your software using a language you don't know because the deployment is thought to be easy.

Answer (score 1):

So something [like this](https://github.com/Modelizer/Laravel-Selenium)? You can install it by

```
composer require modelizer/selenium "~2.0"
```

Comment: yes sir. and i want some sample code or repo that i can make as a reference

Comment: Here's the repo link: https://github.com/Modelizer/Laravel-Selenium . It has a number of examples in it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use Laravel Dusk: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/dusk

While it's intended for testing, works great in prod as well.  I actually have a Selenium docker container running and just point Dusk at that instead of using the local binary.